# Introductory Holography Resources

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, mathematical-physics, conformal-geometry, conformal-field-theory

I'm looking for mathematically rigorous introductory resources (as rigorous as an introduction can be) on the subject of *Holographic Duality* in physics. I require something that adequately covers Anti-de Sitter geometry and the conjectured correspondence with Conformal Field Theory with good physical explanations. I have a background in Differential Geometry at the level of O'Neill's [Semi-Riemannian Geometry](https://www.elsevier.com/books/semi-riemannian-geometry-with-applications-to-relativity/oneill/978-0-12-526740-3). My background in Algebra is upto Gorodentsev's [Algebra I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-45285-2) and [II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-50853-5). Lots of diagrams and visualisations to help capture the intuition would be welcome! It would also be great if the resource was comprehensive and covers advanced topics as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I do not mind a bunch of different sources as well, so long as they're not all too lengthy.

Answer (score 3):

[String Theory and Holographic Duality](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/), MIT Open Coursware, Fall 2014, Instructor Prof. Hong Liu.